# Relationship between eigenvalues of Hermetian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that we have two $m\times m$ matrices $A$ and $B$ which are Hermetian, with $|B_{ij}|\leq |A_{ij}|$ for $i,j = 1,2 \cdots, m$. Can we say anything about the relationship between the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$? For instance, is it true that $|\lambda_{max}(A)| \geq |\lambda_{max}(B)|$?

Comment: If $A = -2I_m$ and $B = -I_m$, then $|B_{ij}| \le |A_{ij}|$ for all $i,j$, but $\lambda_{max}(A) = -2 < -1 = \lambda_{max}(B)$. You might want to modify your conjecture.

Comment: Thanks! I should have meant the magnitudes of the largest eigenvalues. I have modified accordingly.

Comment: I think the OP has to restrict is quest to symmetric definite positive matrices.

Comment: The modified conjecture is still false. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm\sqrt{2}$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $2,0$

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that there is no apparent relationship between the largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ then.